# Have border reach the top and bottom in bootstrap column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to develop my own "card" template in bootstrap 3. If I have a header, then I want there to be a bottom border. This works if I override the margin-left and margin-right that is set by bootstraps row class.

But when trying to have a border-right (or border-left) when using columns, I can't get the border to go all the way to the top and bottom. I tried offsetting the padding, but that made it look really bad.

See the middle card in my example on bootply: http://www.bootply.com/NX5942x2KC

Here's the code for that:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="row card-content-container">
            <div class="col-xs-4 card-left">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                        <span>Left Side</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 card-right">
                <span>Right side</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
body {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

.container {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.card {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card-header-top {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }

.card-content-container {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.card-left {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
  }
```

How do I make my border-right, on the "left side" column go all the way to the top and bottom so it touches the card borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding from `.card-content-container` and then add it to `card-left` and `card-right`.

```
.card-content-container {
   /* padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;*/
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.card-content-container > div{
  padding:5px;
 }
```

See this updated [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/pe1yuGFbKw).

Answer (score 0):

Your `.card-content-container` class has a padding of 5px for top & bottom.

I would suggest removing the padding here:

```
.card-content-container {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

and adding this style:

```
.card-content-container>div {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

[Updated bootply](http://www.bootply.com/vBESdW6CGz)